# How to make phonecalls on an Android AVD?

Tags: calls, android-emulator

I am new to Android SDK and AVDs and I was wondering if there is anyway I can enable the cellular network on an Android AVD and make for example phone calls.

Comment: Do you use Eclipse as IDE?

Comment: No.I do not like Eclipse.I use Netbeans.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can call between AVD's. Run 2 AVD, each will have diffrent number - it is placed on window title bar, example 5558. Call from one to other using this numbers. You can also text ;]

In your AVD you simply cannot use real celluar network because your PC/Mac do not have built-in GSM modem (even if, AVD is not supporting this kind of feature).

Comment: Thanks for your help.I tried it between 2 AVDs and it works.

Comment: Some laptops do have built in 3g modems.  If you had one of those, would it be possible to route a call over the celluar network?

Comment: It can't support this king of feature.This is what fones explains in the last sentence in the parenthesis.Unless he/she is wrong.    :)